# What is "406-Not Acceptable Response" in HTTP?

Tags: json, rest, http, http-response-codes, http-status-code-406

In my Ruby on Rails application I tried to upload an image through the POSTMAN [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) client in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format. When I POST the image I am getting a *406 Not Acceptable Response*. When I checked my database, the image was there and was successfully saved.

What is the reason for this error, is there anything I need to specify in my header?

My request:

URL ---    `http://localhost:3000/exercises.json`

Header:

```
Content-Type  -  application/json
```

Raw data:

```
{
    "exercise": {
        "subbodypart_ids": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "name": "Exercise14"
    },
    "image_file_name": "Pressurebar Above.jpg",
    "image":"******base64 Format*******"
}
```

Comment: https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=616&h=462&f=n&hash=xVJK7ZdOpkO%2FUh2xhFyZsGMsrjA%3D&ora=1%2CaFBCTXdkRmpGL2lvQUFBPQ%2CxAVta9Er0Vinkhwfjw8177yE41y87UNCVordEGXyD3u0qYrdfyHqfMWMLLr0uQxFKi8clAY7LfL6EmGyD5fqKojmf9sni8G0do27dA4BYBI3iSdF_NQ8

Comment: @Dexygen "Page not found"

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Your operation did not fail.

Your backend service is saying that the response type it is returning is not provided in the *Accept* HTTP header in your Client request.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

1. Find out the response (content type) returned by Service.
2. Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code -> 406

Comment: Hi, When you say "Find out the response (content type) returned by the service"? How might I check this? I am returning json from a php file so Im presuming the content type will be json (or do i need to specify this in the headers of the php file?) also I provided this content type in my request header like so 'Accept':'application/json'. would this be correct? 
thanks

Comment: @Sarah I don't know what headers of a php file could be. The question was about HTTP - so it is about the request header. That should be: "Accept: application/json" - without quotation marks. If you return json you have something like this as response content: {"valueX":"abcdefg", "valueY":12}.

Answer (score 52):

> 406 Not Acceptable
>           The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not
>   acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

406 happens when the server cannot respond with the accept-header specified in the request.
In your case it seems application/json for the response may not be acceptable to the server.

Comment: You don't have remove the header, you will have to supply a different one which is acceptable to the server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types

Comment: Who said something about remove? He probably has to send one along at all.

Answer (score 9):

You mentioned you're using Ruby on Rails as a backend. You didn't post the code for the relevant method, but my guess is that it looks something like this:

```
def create
  post = Post.create params[:post]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => post }
  end
end
```

Change it to:

```
def create
  post = Post.create params[:post])
  render :json => post
end
```

And it will solve your problem. It worked for me :)

Comment: Doesn't really sound that you know what you are doing. :)

Answer (score 7):

"Sometimes" this can mean that the server had an internal error, and wanted to respond with an error message (ex: 500 with JSON payload) but since the request headers didn't say it accepted JSON, it returns a 406 instead.  Go figure. (in this case: spring boot webapp).

In which case, your operation did fail.  But the failure message was obscured by another.

Answer (score 5):

Changing header to `Accept: */*` resolved my issue and make sure you don't have any other Accept Header

Comment: Only makes sense if you don't care about the result content.

Answer (score 4):

You can also receive a 406 response when invalid cookies are stored or referenced in the browser - for example, when running a Rails server in Dev mode locally.

If you happened to run two different projects on the same port, the browser might reference a cookie from a different localhost session.

This has happened to me...tripped me up for a minute. Looking in browser > Developer Mode > Network showed it.

Answer (score 4):

```
const request = require('request');

const headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'request',
};

const options = {
    url: "https://example.com/users/6",
    headers:  headers
};

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can give a short explanation as to what this does? ;P

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

solved my problem completely.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all for the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'request.js' you might use the following:

```
var options = {
  url: 'localhost',
  method: 'GET',
  headers:{
    Accept: '*/*'
  }
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case for a API in .NET-Core, the api is set to work with XML (by default is set to response with JSON), so I add this annotation in my Controller :

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase {...}
```

Thank you for putting me on the path !

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to a **firewall blocking the request**. In my case the request payload contained string properties - **"like %abc%"** and ampersand symbol **"&"** - which caused the firewall to think it is a security risk (eg. a sql injection attack) and it blocked the request. Note here the request does not actually go to the server but is returned at the firewall level itself.

In my case, there were no application server logs generated so I knew that the request did not actually reach the server and was blocked before that. The logs that helped me were Web application firewall (WAF) logs.