# Is it possible to return a JSONArray with @ResponseBody in Spring MVC?

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use AJAX to load a URL that will return data from my controller, I need the data to be JSONArray but when it makes the call I get a 406 not acceptable error. Is there an yway that I can return this with @ResponseBody? I can't seem to find a solution online. I've already added the Jackson dependency to my project.

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/TeamBravo/graphs/dimple/WEEK',
    success : function(data) {
        var dataForDimpleWeek = data;
    }
});
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/dimple/{timeScale}")
@ResponseBody
public JSONArray getDimpleData(@PathVariable("timeScale") String timeScale){

    JSONArray tweetsForDimple = new JSONArray();
    if(timeScale.equals("WEEK")){
        tweetsForDimple = getGraphWeekData(); //Returns JSONArray
    }else if(timeScale.equals("MONTH")){
        tweetsForDimple = getGraphMonthData();
    }
    return tweetsForDimple;
}
```

any help would be most appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try adding dataType: "json" to ajax call

Comment: I tried that there, it's still giving me the 406 Not Acceptable error

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924649/406-error-when-consuming-restful-webservice-in-spring-mvc-project-the-webservic

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/dimple")`
    `@ResponseBody`
    `public JSONArray getDimpleData(){`
        `JSONArray tweetsForDimple = new JSONArray();`
        `return tweetsForDimple;`
`}`

Try this simpler version and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just answered a post like this, check out my answer here: [Converting Java object to JSONObject and transmit it at GET method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722471/converting-java-object-to-jsonobject-and-transmit-it-at-get-method/28727990#28727990).

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. I downvoted you here and in the other response as you did exactly the same. OP wants to return JSONObject, not convert to GSON. This should be also a comment not a response