# 406 respond from server (json)

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get json data from  server with JS function (Ajax), but keep receiving 406 status.

In request header I have (among other):

```
GET /projects.json HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

And in response:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So what else? I've set accept type but still couldn't get the data. Similarly, with php/curl I am getting the data as it should.

Comment: This question/rep might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Comment: It helped me so far as I added 'Accept' field in request. But server still respond with 406.