# Retrofit2 - 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: android, retrofit2

When I use **postman** to communicate with the endpoint it's work fine but with **Retrofit2** I get `406 Not Acceptable` message as shown in the *LogCat*. I found some related questions in SO I tried the accepted answer solution *(add the content type in the header)* but doesn't work for me

**Retrofit Config**

```
public interface AndroidAppService {
....
@Headers({
      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" // I also tried application/json
  }) @GET("subscribers/{msisdn}/verify") Observable<HeaderResponse> checkPhoneNumber(
      @Path("msisdn") String phoneNumber);
....
class Factory {
public static AndroidAppService create(String baseUrl) {

  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
      .client(client)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
      .build();
  return retrofit.create(AndroidAppService.class);
  }
 } 
}
```

**LogCat**

```
08-13 18:59:02.376 17766-22236/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: --> GET http://androidapp.net/bo/web/app_dev.php/api/subscribers/0827873/verify http/1.1
08-13 18:59:02.376 17766-22236/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: --> END GET

08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: <-- 406 Not Acceptable http://com.androidapp.com
/bo/web/app_dev.php/api/subscribers/072736263/verify (10680ms)
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 13 Aug 2016 18:58:07 GMT
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: X-Debug-Token: d28d0a
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: X-Debug-Token-Link: http://com.androidapp/bo/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/d28d0a
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1471113729149
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1471113729517
08-13 18:42:09.512 6350-6927/com.androidapp D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the response and specify `Accept` header accordingly. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252326/5250273.

*Hint:* Find out what the difference between `Accept` and `Content-Type` is.

Comment: @Thanks I missed the difference between `Content-Type` and `Accept`