# 406 (Not Acceptable) iron-ajax

Tags: ajax, polymer, http-status-code-406

This is my code.

```
 <iron-ajax auto
                id="requestRepos"    
                url="myurl"
                params='{"mycommaseperatedparams"}'
                handle-as="json"
                on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
```

If i manually hit the url in the broswer, it works. But this one does't.
It's a GET request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP status code `406` means that the server cannot return a representation which conforms to the `Accept-` headers. From the [specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7):

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

For more answers see here: [What is "406-Not Acceptable Response" in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http)

This is most likely the the `Accept` header set to `application/json` by the `iron-ajax` element. The browser (Chrome) on the other hand by default sends requests with

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

Where the `*/*` bit matches any content type.

To fix you would have to work on the server side to allow JSON responses. You could also try setting the header explicitly although I expect iron-ajax to override `Accept` header anyway

```
<iron-ajax headers='{"Accept": "*/*"}' handle-as="json"></iron-ajax>
```

Again, the `*/*` is just an example. You probably need a more specific media type.

Comment: You are a life saver! `headers='{"Accept": "*/*"}'` solved my issue. Thanks a TONN!

Comment: And I also read the explanation. Now I've come to know the exact cause. Thanks.