# 406 (Not Acceptable) error while doing inline validation for email

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing inline validation for emailId and checking whether emailid already exists or not in database but I am getting this error  406 (Not Acceptable).
 For almost every email testcase it is working fine only for one case it is getting failed and i am getting this error in developer tool

> GET https://localhost:9002/provisioning-console/json/user/get/user/email-id/fff@dd.cc?ts=1480929984199 406 (Not Acceptable)

**user-add-panel.html**

```
<div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9 controls">
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="emailId" name="emailId" autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="addUser.email" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" ng-change="invokeChangeEventEmailId()" ng-blur="invokeOnBlurEventEmail(addUser.email)" ng-pattern="emailpattern"
    placeholder="{{::'placeholder.addUser.emailId'|translate}}" required="true" ng-maxlength="254" />
  </div>
```

**user-add-panel.js**

```
$scope.invokeOnBlurEventEmail = function(email) {

  if (email == null) {
    $scope.emailvalidating = false;
  } else {

    $scope.emailvalidating = true;
  }

  var getRolePromise = userDetails.getUserByEmail(email);
  getRolePromise.then(function(response) {
    $scope.addUserForm.emailId.$setValidity('unique', false);
    $scope.emailvalidating = false;

  }, function(error) {
    $scope.addUserForm.emailId.$setValidity('unique', true);

    if (error.errorCode === 'error.invalid.email') {
      $scope.emailvalidating = false;
    } else {
      toasty.serviceError(error);
      $scope.emailvalidating = false;
    }
  });
}
```

This is my service which is calling the API

**user-state.js**

```
getUserByEmail: function(emailId) {

  var defer = $q.defer();
  restClientTemplate.execute({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'json/user/get/user/email-id/' + emailId,

  }).then(function(response) {

    defer.resolve(response.results);
  }, function(response) {
    defer.reject(response);

  });
  return defer.promise;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http)

Comment: i tried still getting same error any other suggestion

Comment: _For almost every email testcase it is working fine only for one case it is getting failed_ **Can you let me know in which case?**

Comment: when i am adding .cc at the end for example tanejapriyanka42@gmail.cc then spinner is keep on rotating and m  getting 406 error

Comment: I am using this regex /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;  its working fine for all other testcases except .cc at the end

Comment: Try this: ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\+]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) still the same issue.

Comment: Instead of @PAthVariale i tried Request PAram its working fine now. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.cc might have special significance in URI pattern.Solution

1. if using @PathVariable specify the acceptable regex for email
2. easy way is to use @ReqeustParam

Answer (score 0):

Try URI encoding the email.

```
url:'json/user/get/user/email-id/'+ encodeURIComponent(emailId),
```

Comment: i tried still getting same error any other suggestion?