# Volley Library returning 406 exception

Tags: android, android-volley

I am developing android application where volley library working fine on some devices whereas on other device it is returing 406 exception for same request.

Postman also returning proper result with same request.

```
   public void doPostOperation()
    {

        IOUtils.startLoadingPleaseWait(mContext);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, requestUrl, jsonRequest, listenerSuccess, listenerError)
        {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
            {

                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Cookie", Preference.getInstance(mContext).getData(Constants.Cookie));
                headers.put("X-CSRF-Token", Preference.getInstance(mContext).getData(Constants.Token));
                return headers;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60 * 1000, 1, 1.0f));
        app.addToRequestQueue(request, "post");
    }
```

Request -

{"password":"Distributor2","username":"Distributor2"}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Comment: Did u check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http)?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner   She mentioned it's working on some devices and not working on others. So this might not be the issue.

Comment: Please show your code. The part of the code where you are submitting the request and the data that you are sending in the request. The links already posted in the comments section already highlights what is the cause of a HTTP 406.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner- Its working on emulator and postman but for tablet it is returning 406 exception.

Comment: @Dibzmania-  added code and request