# What does a 406 (Not Acceptable) error code from elasticsearch mean?

Tags: javascript, ajax, elasticsearch

I am trying to use [`qwest`](http://dreamysource.io/project/qwest) to send some data to Elasticsearch:

```
qwest.post(
    'http://elk.example.com:9200/incidents',
    this.incident,
    {cache: true}
)
    .then(function (xhr, response) {
        console.log('incident posted')
    })
    .catch(function (e, xhr, response) {
        console.log('error posing incident: ' + e)
    })
```

where `this.incident` is an `Object` (from Vue.js).

The call fails with a `406 (Not Acceptable)` error, which I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252326/903011) being an information from the Elasticsearch server telling me that I wanted an answer in some format, which he cannot use.

The call fails (there is no document indexed) nevertheless, so I am not sure if my understanding is correct?

If so - what is a correct format to ask for?

Comment: Do you want to create a new document and also create the index at the same time?

Comment: @Val: yes, for the first call. But then also use the same call to index a new document (when the index has been created by the first call). I can create the index manually if this helps (I thought it did not matter)

Comment: @Val: I just tried to create the index first (`PUT /incidents`), the index was created and reissuing the call in my question leads to the same issue (so it does not matter whether the index is present or not)

Comment: note that you're using `post` and not `put`. Also the URL should have a document type, i.e. `http://elk.example.com:9200/incidents/incident`. It will probably work after that

Comment: @Val: you are right, I forgot to add the document type in my request. This did not solve the issue, though.

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, still the 406

Comment: How does the error look like in your ES server log?

Comment: There are no errors in the log. I tried with a plain jQuery AJAX call, same thing (so this is not an issue with the library). I then tried to GET the status (call to a bare `http://example.com:9200`) and I get a result (via Javascript). So this is really the `POST` part which fails (you mentioned `PUT` but a `POST` of some data with `curl` was successful)

Comment: Are you sure that your `incident` object gets serialized as JSON ?

Comment: @Val: that was it, I was passing an Object (dictionary) which was then encoded and (I assume) sent with the default encode to ES. Would you mind just bootstrap an answer, I will then add code that works (serialized JSON and `application/json` type) - you had the right idea so the glory and delude of rep is yours :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `incident` object is not a properly serialized JSON string. You need to call `JSON.stringify(this.incident)` in order to get the equivalent JSON string, and specify the `application/json` HTTP header.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com:9200/incidents/incidents',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(this.incident),
            dataType: 'json'
        })
```