# Facing a issue when returning json with ResponseEntity in spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot and I need to pass JSON list in @RestController using ResponseEntity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity getCustomers() {

        List<Customer> customerJsonList = new ArrayList();
        List<CustomerTable> customerList = (List<CustomerTable>) customerRepository.findAll();

        for(CustomerTable customerTable : customerList) {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(customerTable.getId());
            customer.setFirstname(customerTable.getFirstname());
            customer.setLastname(customerTable.getLastname());
            customer.setAddress(customerTable.getAddress());
            customerJsonList.add(customer);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(customerJsonList);
    }
```

When I tried to test in postman I get an empty body. When I tried in Chrome browser I am getting:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Mon Dec 11 10:19:54 AEDT 2017
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
>   Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should specify a mapping value, try something like :

> @RequestMapping(value = "mymappingurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)

After that, try your url with "mymappingurl" appended to it. Right now, the servlet container goes to fallback url host/error for which you don't have anything configured either, hence you see this response.

Answer (score 0):

After adding

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

It is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Have your Method return 
`ResponseEntity<?> getCustomers()`

Then Rerun below:

`return new ResponseEntity<List<Customer>>(customerJsonList,HttpStatus.OK);`

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        List<Customer> customerJsonList = new ArrayList();
        List<CustomerTable> customerList = (List<CustomerTable>) customerRepository.findAll();

        for(CustomerTable customerTable : customerList) {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(customerTable.getId());
            customer.setFirstname(customerTable.getFirstname());
            customer.setLastname(customerTable.getLastname());
            customer.setAddress(customerTable.getAddress());
            customerJsonList.add(customer);
        }

        return customerJsonList;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.