# How to Post to restful web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post to my API that accepts JSON format data

I however get a 406 not acceptable error.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var user = "demo";
var password = "demo";
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{user}:{password}"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64String);
string url = "https://api.fever.co.za/FTIntegration.svc/BalanceLookup";
var data = new
{
    BalanceID = "4E45D053-044E-4C7E-A2A3-0743A7237811",
    CardOrIDNumber = "8212225222075"
};
var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, stringContent );
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: I prefer to use restsharp (http://restsharp.org/) to post, get or any other rest api request. It is very simple and useful library.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. In particular half of your code is not used at all and you are missing server side portion.

Comment: updated the code and serialized once - still get the 406 error

Comment: You need to send another header `Accept` with value `application/json`

Comment: @RadhiyahWilliams `PostAsJsonAsync` already does the serializing of the data for you. What you had originally with `var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data);` should be fine. You have not shown the serverside of things which is probably where the issue is.

Comment: Try clearing the accept header before adding your desired type `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()`

Comment: tried that aswell error persists - the server side returns data in json format- i do not have access to the server just the credentials and endpoint url

Comment: @RadhiyahWilliams You stated that the API was your API. What is the content type of the current response. check that.

Comment: ("Content-Type", "application/json")

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem may be solved by this response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252326/6996150

> Your operation did not fail.
>
> Your backend service is saying that the response type it is returning
>   is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.
>
> Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
>
> - Find out the response (content type) returned by Service.
> - Provide this
>     (content type) in your request Accept header.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code -> 406

(credits to @TheWhiteRabbit)

Comment: added the Accept header aswell as content type error persist 406 not acceptable