# App cannot send and retrieve files from server via php mysql

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, android-volley

I have a page in my app with similar codes with different values and they send info to my PHP MySQL just fine. On the other hand, this page in my app cannot send the files and giving me an error message:

```
 E/Volley: [258] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 406 
 for http://applybpojobs.com/widevalueappfiles/server/api/addvehicle.php
```

I have already tried numerous solutions on web and this site to no avail. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Here is my java:

```
public class Addvehicle extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = Addvehicle.class.getSimpleName();
private EditText plate_number, vin, car_make, car_model, car_year, displacement,
        fuel_type, transmission, mileage, owner_name, address, phone_number,
        email_adress, facebook;
private TextView btnCreate;
private TextView btnClose;
private ImageView upload_car, preview;
private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

private static String URL_ADD_VEHICLE = "http://abcde/server/api/addvehicle.php";
//private static String URL_VEHICLE_IMAGE = "http://abcde/server/api/addvehicle.php";
private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addvehicle);

    requestMultiplePermissions();

    /*EditText Area*/
    plate_number =          findViewById(R.id.plate_number);
    vin =                   findViewById(R.id.vin);
    car_make =              findViewById(R.id.car_make);
    car_model =             findViewById(R.id.car_model);
    car_year =              findViewById(R.id.car_year);
    displacement =          findViewById(R.id.displacement);
    fuel_type =             findViewById(R.id.fuel_type);
    transmission =          findViewById(R.id.transmission);
    mileage =               findViewById(R.id.mileage);
    owner_name =            findViewById(R.id.owner_name);
    address =               findViewById(R.id.address);
    phone_number =          findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    email_adress =          findViewById(R.id.email_adress);
    facebook =              findViewById(R.id.facebook);

    /*TextView Area*/

    btnClose =              findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    btnCreate =             findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);

    /*Button Area*/

    upload_car = findViewById(R.id.iv);
    preview = findViewById(R.id.iv);

    upload_car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPictureDialog();
        }
    });

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Addvehicle.this, Home.class));
        }
    });

    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showLoader();
            addVehicle(getStringImage(bitmap));
        }
    });


}

private void showPictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {
            "Select photo from gallery",
            "Capture photo from camera" };
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallary();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            takePhotoFromCamera();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}

public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}

private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {


        if (data != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                String path = getStringImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            addVehicle(getStringImage(bitmap));


        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        preview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        getStringImage(thumbnail);
        Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    addVehicle(getStringImage(bitmap));


}


private void addVehicle(final String stringImage) {
    final String plate_number = this.plate_number.getText().toString().trim();
    final String vin = this.vin.getText().toString().trim();
    final String car_make = this.car_make.getText().toString().trim();
    final String car_model = this.car_model.getText().toString().trim();
    final String car_year = this.car_year.getText().toString().trim();
    final String displacement = this.displacement.getText().toString().trim();
    final String fuel_type = this.fuel_type.getText().toString().trim();
    final String transmission = this.transmission.getText().toString().trim();
    final String mileage = this.mileage.getText().toString().trim();
    final String owner_name = this.owner_name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String address = this.address.getText().toString().trim();
    final String phone_number = this.phone_number.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email_adress = this.email_adress.getText().toString().trim();
    final String facebook = this.facebook.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ADD_VEHICLE,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String Success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        if (Success.equals("1")){
                            hideLoader();
                            Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else if (Success.equals("0")){
                            hideLoader();
                            Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        hideLoader();
                        Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Added Error"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Toast.makeText(Addvehicle.this,"Vehicle Added Error"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hideLoader();
                }
            })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("plate_number", plate_number);
            params.put("vin", vin);
            params.put("car_make", car_make);
            params.put("car_model", car_model);
            params.put("car_year", car_year);
            params.put("displacement", displacement);
            params.put("fuel_type", fuel_type);
            params.put("transmission", transmission);
            params.put("mileage", mileage);
            params.put("owner_name", owner_name);
            params.put("address", address);
            params.put("phone_number", phone_number);
            params.put("email_adress", email_adress);
            params.put("facebook", facebook);
            params.put("photo", stringImage);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

public void showLoader(){
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Adding Vehicle...");
    progressDialog.show();
}

public void hideLoader(){
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.hide();
}


public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] imageByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void  requestMultiplePermissions(){
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    // check if all permissions are granted
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // check for permanent denial of any permission
                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                        //openSettingsDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }

            }).
            withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(DexterError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })

            .onSameThread()
            .check();
}
```

This is my server api file (mysqli) which is giving me the error response from logcat with this url : "http://abcde/server/api/addvehicle.php"

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require '../core/connect.php';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $plate_number=$_POST['plate_number'];
    $vin=$_POST['vin'];
    $car_make=$_POST['car_make'];
    $car_model=$_POST['car_model'];
    $car_year=$_POST['car_year'];
    $displacement=$_POST['displacement'];
    $fuel_type=$_POST['fuel_type'];
    $transmission=$_POST['transmission'];
    $mileage=$_POST['mileage'];
    $owner_name=$_POST['owner_name'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
    $email_adress=$_POST['email_adress'];
    $facebook=$_POST['facebook'];
    $adddate = date("d/m/Y");

    $photo = $_POST['photo'];

    $id=uniqid();


    $path = "vehicle_upload/$id.jpeg";
    $finalpath = 
"http://abcde/server/api/addvehicle.php".$path;


$sql1=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM _addvehicle WHERE 
PlateNumber='$plate_number'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql1) > 0) {
            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";
            echo json_encode($result);
    }else{

        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT IGNORE INTO 
_addvehicle(PlateNumber, Vin, Make, Model, Year, Displacement, FuelType, 
Transmission, Mileage, OwnerorCompany, HomeorCompanyAddress, ContactNumber, 
EmailAddress, FacebookID, AddDate, vehicleImage)VALUES('$plate_number','$vin','$car_make','$car_model','$car_year','$displacement','$fuel_type','$transmission','$mileage','$owner_name','$address','$phone_number','$email_adress','$facebook','$adddate','$finalpath')");

        if ($sql) {


                if (file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($photo))) {
                    $result['success'] = "1";
                    $result['message'] = "success";
                    echo json_encode($result);
                    //mysqli_close($connect);
                }

            }
    }
```

I am having a hard time identifying what went wrong. Although I am seeing that logcat points me to the php file, it doesn't specifically tell me what to change. This page was working a couple of days ago.

Comment: dude maintain some privacy, your data on your domain is exposed and its clearly seen what all domains and contents you have put there

Comment: @PareshMayani thanks for the reminder. I switched it to a pseudo url. But you didn't give me an actual answe though :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Comment: regarding PHP part, better debug it through a browser