# Retrofit2 Not acceptable response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm actually trying to get a response from my endpoint, but I'm facing a weird issue, I'm getting a 406 HTTP code in Retrofit response.

This is the body of my request I'm sending:

```
   {
    "login":"34413",
    "otp":"51131"
    }
```

when I send to correct OTP, I get the response from my endpoint

```
{
   "statusResponse":    {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "success": succes
   },
   "person": [object person],
   "token": "...."
}
```

but in case I'm sending the wrong OTP number, I get a retrofit response code 406 which means I didn't receive anything from my endpoint.

**NB :**
when i try my request from SOAP UI both case works fine and this is the response of wrong otp case :

```
    {
   "statusResponse":    {
      "statusCode": 406,
      "success": false
   },
   "person": null,
   "token": null
}
```

Do you have any idea what causing the issue?

Comment: its correct behaviour rt? when succes u get 200 otherwise 406

Comment: yeah but i should get it from my endpoint response as shown , and not from retrofit response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252326/3796083 check this answer do you have an http login interceptor in retrofit? You can debug request/response header, body, etc.

Comment: yes i have one and i already checked this answer , but this is not my case ! because it works perfectly when i send the correct otp code and not when it's a wrong otp number ! ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think retrofit is returning the same response as your soap client as long as the request is the same. If no interceptors are involved.

The common issue is that you are probably expecting the response body to have your json, however with Retrofit in case of unsuccessful response you have to check the **errorbody** instead of the **body** then call `string()` to get its content.

Comment: thanks , you are right , i solved by getting my json as you suggest ,  this way :
jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());