# amp-list index.js:59 Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed fetching JSON data: HTTP error 406​

Tags: php, json, amp-html, http-status-code-406, amp-list

In a **amp-list** element, when I use a json file to load data, for exemple:

**src="amp-listing.json"**, it works fine.

But when I use a json generate from a php script, for exemple: **src="amp-listing.php"**, I have the error:

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed fetching JSON data: HTTP error 406​​​**

```
at ya (index.js:59)
at yb.g.createError (log.js:344)
at xhr-utils.js:384
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at qg (xhr-utils.js:378)
at xhr-impl.js:184
```

I found that the problem is that AMP adds to the json request, the parameter **__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourdomain.com**

And the **Apache mod_security** module doesn't like **%2F** giving the error:

*Not Acceptable!
An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.*

If I try **__amp_source_origin=https://www.yourdomain.com** it works properly! But of course, AMP encodes special characters.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Pau

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 406 error code, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a rule to **mod_security** in order to accept the **%2F** characters in the **request URL**.