# How to get response JSON of an API which returns Http Status Code 406 or 400

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, rest

Postman returns some response JSON with HTTP status code 406 but my code which is written in C# returns the same HTTP status code error message but from Catch Block.

**My Requirement is**

The API I am consuming always returns some response JSON either the HTTP status code 200 or 400 or any other. When I test these API from post man it show response JSON but my code returns error when I execute the following line.

**HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();**

Here is my complete method.

```cs
private Dictionary<string, string> HTTPCall(CRMRequestData requestData, out bool isError, out string errorMessage)
        {
            isError = true;
            errorMessage = "HTTPCall - initial error!";
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = TLS12;

                Dictionary<string, string> responseBag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestData.Uri);
                
                request.Method = requestData.HttpMethodName;
                request.ContentType = requestData.ContentType;
                request.ContentLength = string.Format("{0}", requestData.Body).Length;
                request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", requestData.APIKey);
                if (requestData.Authorization != null)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("JWT {0}",requestData.Authorization));
                }

                if (requestData.HttpMethodName.ToUpper().Equals("POST"))
                {
                    string body = requestData.Body;
                    Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//#Error at this line

                
                string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                if (responseData != null && responseData != "")
                {
                    responseBag = ReadResponseJSON(responseData, requestData.CRMMethod, out isError, out errorMessage);
                }

                errorMessage = (!isError) ? "HTTPCall - API executed successfully!" : errorMessage;
                return responseBag;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isError = true;
                errorMessage = string.Format("{0}", ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**Note: -*
My code block works fine when API returns the HTTP status code 200 or 201

[image]

Comment: Using HttpWebRequest, Status Codes above 399 are treated as exceptions. Catch the specific `WebException` instead of a generic Exception: if the Response is not dropped, you can still read its content (in these cases, the exception can contain a non-null Response object and a StatusCode).

Comment: Thanks Jimi! I got it.  Now, In **WebException** object, I am not able to find out the response content like the postman screenshot.

Comment: If the Response object is not null and Response.ContentLength is > 0, you have to read it. -- It's probably simpler if you use HttpClient instead (.Net 3.5 ? For real?).

Comment: I am using HttpWebRequest in **.NETv3.5**. Response.ContentLength > 100 but I am not able to see response JSON string

Comment: The content is a Stream, you have to read it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jimi. It is working perfectly when I am reading the content as a stream

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[What is "406-Not Acceptable Response" in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http)

In short: Add Accept header for the response (content type) returned by Service