# HTTP POST and GET works perfectly with POSTMAN app and React Native app but not with Python requests

Tags: react-native, codeigniter, http, python-requests, postman

Background: I am developing an application based on codeigniter-4 to host my APIs', react native for mobile-application and python3 scripts to upload data to my server (ci4-api) from my desktop.

*What is working:* I can request/connect to server via POSTMAN app, also I can connect to server from react native app as follows, both shows successful

```
response = await fetch(url, {method: 'GET'});
```

*what is not working*: when I request by using python `requests` it throws 406 error, code below

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError 

# url is removed 

try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occured: {err}')
else:
    print('Success')
```

out >> HTTP error occurred: 406 Client Error: Not Acceptable for url:

In codeigniter I am using `get` method in routes. Please let me know your feedback why it fails in `python`

I have also tried POST method, it is not inserting any data to database in python

```
payload = { 'id':'sdfr234', 'name' : 'An 23', 'phoneNumber' : '96529', 'password':'qwerty' } 
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json' } 
response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "406-Not Acceptable Response" in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http)

Comment: I tried to use `post` instead of `get` , also added the headers and then checked the database. Getting same  message 406, more over no data added to database. `payload = { 'id':'sdfr234', 'name' : 'An 23', 'phoneNumber' : '96529', 'password':'qwerty' }`

`headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json' }` response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, json=payload)`

Comment: Instead of `requests`  when I use `http.client`, I get response as I expected. I don't know the exact issue with `requests`