# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) during javascript api call

Tags: javascript, api, drupal, fetch-api

I am making a fetch api POST request to a url. It responds with a 406 error. Here is my code:

```
function arCall(url = '', data = {}) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'cors', 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/html, */*',
      'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.text();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
}

arCall('<my URL>', { id: 100 });
```

I looked at this question [What is "406-Not Acceptable Response" in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http) and based on that, added `*/*` to the 'Accept' header. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Here are some of the details of the header response:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
Server: Apache
X-Generator: Drupal 9 (https://www.drupal.org)
X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details of your header response (as in the cms is Drupal) and the fact that setting 'Accept' to `*/*` didn't work, I think the problem could be with your URL.

According to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258823/drupal-8-5-rest-406-not-acceptable, you need to add `?_format=FORMAT` at the end of your URL if you haven't already done so. Since this is Drupal, I think the format would either be `hal_json` or `json` though I can't say for sure. You would have to go on to the 'Network' tab of your inspect option on your browser to analyze the response header.